# Viewstate is lost after applying for a job

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

Suppose I apply a few filters on Stack Overflow jobs, search job postings and then apply for particular job using *Easy Apply*.

After this, I am redirected to the home page I guess, and all the filters I applied are lost.

Can you maintain state of the filters applied and the scrollbar position?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if those two things are related. Are you blocking cookies?

Comment: Related: *[Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208)*

Comment: I am using latest firefox 79, the issue is when I "Easy apply" a job the filters go away, I am redirected to default page

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the report! I marked this post as declined simply because I can't commit to resolving this. Technically this is by-design (not good design, but that's how it's always worked AFAIK), but I agree it can be a hassle so I've submitted it as a bug so at least it's being tracked.